# Java regex to add space after closing tag if its not present

Tags: java, html, regex

I have following html string and I want to add space after all tags like `</strong>` where space is missing, only inside body. If there is a space already, extra space should not be added.

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head><body>This <strong>Super</strong> subject can be <strong>super</strong>test into object</body></html>
```

This should get converted to following:

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head><body>This <strong>Super</strong> subject can be <strong>super</strong> test into object</body></html>
```

Is this doable using regex? Can you help me with the regex?

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("(?<=</strong>)(?! )", " ")` --- See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4qQhJl/1/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex, which will look for any closing tag (in the form `</zzzz>`) that is not followed by a space, and then replace it with `$1`:

```
(<\/[a-z]+>)(?! )
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8SWYUK/1)

This will modify *any* closing tags in your HTML though. To only modify closing tags within the `body`, you could split the string first into the parts before the `<body`, between that and the closing `</body` and the balance of the string, and then only modify the part in the middle. For example,

```
String s = "<html><head><title>test</title></head><body>This <strong>Super</strong> subject can be <strong>super</strong>test into object</body></html>";
String [] pieces = s.split("</?body");
pieces[1] = pieces[1].replaceAll("(</[a-z]+>)(?! )", "$1 ");
s = pieces[0] + "<body" + pieces[1] + "</body" + pieces[2];
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head><body>This <strong>Super</strong> subject can be <strong>super</strong> test into object</body></html>
```

Comment: this is good, but it adds extra spaces: <html><head><title>test</title> </head>

Comment: @dev009 I interpreted the question as you wanted space after every closing tag... is that not what you want?

Comment: ohh no... not all.. only where there is no space, see the converted text

Comment: @dev009 sorry, what I meant was, after `</title>` etc., or did you just mean after `</strong>`?

Comment: @dev009 see my edit, it gives a way to only do the replacement inside the body

Comment: Ideally would like to have 1 regex for everything :). But this works as well Thanks.

Comment: @dev009 I think that's difficult because of the need to only match after the `<body>` tag. But don't accept the answer yet, it's possible you might get a better one if you leave it open.